How does OpenIdConnectEvents get overrided?
below is the source code:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs,1288
where await Events.AuthorizationCodeReceived(context); must exchange auth code with access code in the backchannel, but according to the source code of OpenIdConnectEvents:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs
public class OpenIdConnectEvents : RemoteAuthenticationEvents
{
    public Func<AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext, Task> OnAuthorizationCodeReceived { get; set; } = 
        context => Task.CompletedTask;
    // ...
}

it does nothing but just returns Task.CompletedTask so this OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event must be override somewhere, but I couldn't see where it is getting override? we users of course cannot write it directly everytime we use openid connect.

OnAuthorizationCodeReceived is just event flag. It doesn't handle the exchange of code and access token.
The await Events.AuthorizationCodeReceived(context); is just a part of action in the RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync method. 
You could check the description above this method which should handle the token exchange :RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync . https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs,987
You could also check this part of code which runs the whole process of "code flow" under HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync : include get code and redeem code for token. https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs,810
